# Why is Touka Kirishima afraid of birds?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I'm not sure when she became afraid of birds. Does it involve something from her childhood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Touka suffers from Ornithophobia, most likely due to being pecked near her eye in her youth by [Chunta](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Chunta). Which is also the reason why she covers her right eye with her hair.

> Chunta (チュンタ, Chunta) was an injured bird that was found by Touka Kirishima and Ayato Kirishima. They nursed the bird back to health, keeping it in a cage at their apartment and feeding it worms they dug up. After their father, Arata Kirishima, disappeared and Touka and Ayato were on the run from Ghoul Investigators, they turned back to release Chunta from his cage. After being freed, he pecked Touka in the eye.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that was why she covered that eye it thought it was he’s sense of style